# Adding strings to MySQL++ queries

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql++

I am trying out [MySQL++](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/) and am looking into queries. I'd like to be able to insert string variables into my queries, so that something like this:

```
query << "CREATE TABLE beer (" 
      << "beerID smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
      << "beerName varchar(30) NOT NULL,"
      << "PRIMARY KEY (beerID));";
```

could be something like:

```
query << "CREATE TABLE " << tableName << " (" 
      << fieldName1 << " smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
      << fieldName2 << " varchar(30) NOT NULL,"
      << "PRIMARY KEY (" << fieldName1 << "));";
```

where *tableName*, *fieldName1*, and *fieldName2* are all some type of string variables that can be modified at runtime so that a user can define the table and field names (and later table data) while the application is running. Is such a thing possible? If so, how? The documentation I've seen isn't very clear on this and I haven't had any success using C++ strings.

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't had any success using c++ strings.

You don't show what errors you get when you try this.

I just modified `examples/resetdb.cpp` like so to do what you're trying:

```
--- examples/resetdb.cpp    (revision 2716)
+++ examples/resetdb.cpp    (working copy)
@@ -132,14 +132,17 @@
        // Send the query to create the stock table and execute it.
        cout << "Creating stock table..." << endl;
        mysqlpp::Query query = con.query();
+       string table_name("stock");
+       string f1("item"), f2("num"), f3("weight"), f4("price"),
+               f5("sdate"), f6("description");
        query <<
-               "CREATE TABLE stock (" <<
-               "  item CHAR(30) NOT NULL, " <<
-               "  num BIGINT NOT NULL, " <<
-               "  weight DOUBLE NOT NULL, " <<
-               "  price DECIMAL(6,2) NULL, " << // NaN & inf. == NULL
-               "  sdate DATE NOT NULL, " <<
-               "  description MEDIUMTEXT NULL) " <<
+               "CREATE TABLE " << table_name << " (" <<
+               f1 << " CHAR(30) NOT NULL, " <<
+               f2 << " BIGINT NOT NULL, " <<
+               f3 << " DOUBLE NOT NULL, " <<
+               f4 << " DECIMAL(6,2) NULL, " << // NaN & inf. == NULL
+               f5 << " DATE NOT NULL, " <<
+               f6 << " MEDIUMTEXT NULL) " <<
                "ENGINE = InnoDB " <<
                "CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
        query.execute();
```

I rebuilt MySQL++ with those changes, re-ran its self-test suite, and it gives the exact same test results as before. If the table structure *had* changed, I would expect many of the tests to fail.

So, you must be doing something else, but I can't guess what from your question.

Answer (score -1):

You should have a look at http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/userman/tutorial.html#qescape

E.g. to produce :

```
SELECT * FROM stock WHERE item = 'Hotdog Buns'
```

You can use :

```
string s = "Hotdog Buns";
query << "SELECT * FROM stock WHERE item = " << quote_only << s;
```

Comment: I get an error "'quote_only' was not declared in this scope" do I need to include another header file, so far it is just:#include </usr/include/mysql++/mysql++.h>
#include "/usr/include/mysql++/cmdline.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

Comment: try including <code>manip.h</code> ! http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/refman/manip_8h.html

Comment: @Fafhrd: No, you don't need to #include `manip.h` directly. It is included indirectly by `mysql++.h`, which the OP says he #included. I'm betting it's a namespace problem. He either needs to say `using namespace mysqlpp` above this code, or qualify the manipulator as `mysqlpp::quote_only`.

Comment: Also, the `quote_only` manipulator is *not* what you want here. That's for string values. The OP is asking about field names, which are either unquoted or quoted with backticks. Some times the backticks are required, but they aren't in any of the code posted so far.